# Local translation with pivot point established on the active object

Tags: modeling, coordinates

Whenever i try to translate objects, with pivot point established on the active object, every object translates in their own local coordinates.
Video will explain it better: youtube.com/watch?v=vArDq7cqRdA

UPD: Okay, i recorded another video to make it less confusing:
youtube.com/watch?v=qFCMPoBb8Ac

firstly i show you what the trouble is, next i select 'individual origins' and there is no difference. And in the end i apply rotation and only then i get what i wanted(and what i expected)
I just wanna make sure that such a behavior is what developers wanted and this is not a bug

Comment: You should also place 2 screen captures in your question beyond the video.  It may give your question a better sense of importance.  The video at the other website  can be deleted anytime which makes the question seem less important and temporary.

Comment: You seem to be changing transformation axis from the video which should be stated in your question.  Your question description above and the video could match better.

Comment: Every piece of software has defects.  I believe what you are talking about is intended.

Comment: Here is a tutorial series if that suits you tastes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a multiple selection with the keystrokes

- <kbd>gz</kbd> global axis

is different than

- <kbd>gzz</kbd> local axis

where the letter z refers to the z axis and can be replaced by any of the set {x, y, z, X, Y, Z}.  Feel free to experiment.

So having a selection of multiple objects move on their locally rotated axis is a feature.

You can [apply] a rotation.  And thus all objects would have the same rotational axis and different origins.

I do not know your long term goals for your model.  Tutorials may lead you to understand how to

- [join] objects
- [parent] objects

  Blender always has various ways to achieve your goal.

So what is written here is not a tutorial, and you may need to search further here at BSE.  Also pay attention to the additional information which appears in Blender 3D View at the bottom, when using either of the keystrokes above.

You may appear to be changing transformation axis although the video may be clipping the lower portion of the screen capture.  You can also change the pivot center.

[image]

I believe Blender is performing as intended.  As the user you should see this behavior as a good option and not something unintended.

In the image below the Blender User first grabbed an object.  Then pressed

- <kbd>F6</kbd>

to see the other options of the grab/translate operator.

[image]

The famous website that rhymes with noonoob has tutorials on selection transformation in Blender.  Although I have not taken the time to find one that deeply addresses this topic you may find one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaYhhaKDh5E

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wklRKGC7ai8